# Selecting Sum of the Count From Tables in a DB

Tags: sql, count, union

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(count) 
  FROM (SELECT 'artist' AS table_name, COUNT(*) as count FROM artist
        UNION
        SELECT 'persons' AS table_name, COUNT(*) as count FROM persons
        UNION
        SELECT 'track' AS table_name, COUNT(*) as count FROM track)
```

It works as expected and returns the proper count. But now when I do the following query I get the incorrect count:

```
SELECT SUM(count) 
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM artist
        UNION
        SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM persons
        UNION
        SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM track)
```

Why is it the first query gets the proper count and the second one does not?

Comment: Can you expound on "incorrect count".  If not the sum you expect can you identify what it is counting?

Comment: It was returning just two of the counts. As @Joe Stefanelli pointed out this was due to counts being eliminated in a UNION

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `UNION` eliminates duplicate values, so if two counts happen to be the same, one is eliminated and only one is summed. Try using `UNION ALL` instead.

```
SELECT sum(count) FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM artist
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM persons
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM track)
```

Comment: Oh wow it was obvious, I gotta work on not forgetting basic SQL haha. Thank you very much!!.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with approximate, just count all tables in one go

```
SELECT
   Total_Rows= SUM(st.row_count)
FROM
   sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
WHERE
   (index_id < 2) --cover both heaps and clustered indexes
   AND
   OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME (object_id) <> 'sys' --ignore system stuff
```

This will run in a flash

Adopting your original, you can get count per table and overall in one go..

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(count) OVER () AS GrandTotal
FROM (SELECT 'artist' AS table_name, COUNT(*) as count FROM artist
    UNION
    SELECT 'persons' AS table_name, COUNT(*) as count FROM persons
    UNION
    SELECT 'track' AS table_name, COUNT(*) as count FROM track)
```

Answer (score 0):

How is it inaccurate? One way might be because, in the second query, you hvae `UNION`, and two or more rows contain the same value--because `UNION` removes duplicate values. Try it with `UNION ALL`, which returns all rows, not just unique ones.