# Adding the count of two tables and then group

Tags: mysql

I have two queries (returning the correct results) where I basically want to combine the counts and then group:

```
Select profileID, 
Count(*) as numTotal from replies
GROUP BY profileID;
```

Result:

```
profileID: 1,2,3   
numTotal: 10,1,1
```

and

```
Select postedByID,
Count(*) as numTotal from WIRL_01.posts 
Group by postedByID
```

Result:

```
postedByID: 1,2,3 
numTotal: 13,4,3
```

In this case, I want to group where profileID = postedByID. I tried the following but to no avail:

```
Select profileID,
Count(*) as numTotal 
from replies
INNER JOIN posts ON replies.profileID = posts.postedByID
Group by profileID
```

Result:

```
postedByID: 1,2,3 
numTotal: 130,4,3
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Edit:

This query gets me a little closer however how do I group the results by profileID?

```
Select profileID, Count(*) from WIRL_01.replies Group by profileID
UNION ALL
Select postedByID, Count(*) from WIRL_01.posts Group by postedByID
```

Gives me...

profileID: 1,2,3,1,2,3
Count(*):10,1,1,13,4,3

What I need is:

profileID: 1,2,3
Count(*):23,5,4

Comment: What was wrong with your JOINed query?

Comment: @AlainCollins I'm not getting the expected result. It looks like the two results are getting multiplied. I'll edit my post with the results for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! :)

```
Select profileID, sum(count) as totalNum from (Select profileID, Count(*) as count from  replies Group by profileID
UNION ALL
Select postedByID, Count(*) as count from posts Group by postedByID) as numTotal
group by profileID
```

Big thanks to Joe Stafanelli: [Selecting Sum of the Count From Tables in a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683608/selecting-sum-of-the-count-from-tables-in-a-db)